# Regex match any of the words separated by slashes

Tags: java, regex, string, matching

I need to develop a validation pattern for catching any kind from:

> pdf/csv/xlsx

select any separate word is simple:

> (pdf|csv|xlsx).

However, I need to check that any combination with them separated by slash is fine as well.

For example, **correct flow**:

```
pdf/csv/xlsx
pdf
pdf/csv
csv/xlsx
xlsx
pdf/xlsx
```

**Incorrect**:

```
test
incorrect
doc
```

Comment: So you have limited number of words that are correct?

Comment: exactly and they could be passed together or separated - and it should be correct

Comment: Is `pdf/pdf` correct, or do we assume that it will never appear?

Comment: `csv/pdf` should be fine as well. `pdf/pdf` should be treated correct as well

Comment: Try: `^(?:pdf|csv|xlsx)(?:/(?:pdf|csv|xlsx))?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
^(?:pdf|csv|xlsx?)(?:/(?:pdf|csv|xlsx?))*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XvBijy/1)

Comment: it is very close. However, it fails for `pdf/csv/xlsx` input. Updated question as well

Comment: ok in that case we need to replace `?` with `*` in the end

Comment: Practically Ivo's solution except with noncapturing groups.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
^(pdf|csv|xlsx)(\/(pdf|csv|xlsx))*$
```

Answer (score 1):

This idea makes the pattern a bit shorter:

```
^(?:(?:pdf|csv|xlsx?)/?\b)+$
```

[Here is a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GaX66Z/1)

The slash is set to [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) here and the [word boundary `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) requires it between words on the one hand and disallows it at the end on the other. It might be a tiny bit less efficient, but looks cool.